# WebView Show only part of Website/ hide a part of the website

Tags: java, android-webview

I am trying to show only part of the website. I am trying to hide the slideshow. For some reason, my code doesn't work and it still shows the whole page. I searched the whole web but couldn't find an answer that worked out for me. I am still a beginner, so sorry if I make some dumb mistakes:)
Thank you in advance!!

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('main-carousel2').style.display='none';", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                Log.e(TAG,value);
            }
        });
    }
});
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.eventster.it");
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've submitted my answer and I saw you've asked the same question earlier. Request you to delete the previous question thanks.

Comment: @SahilManchanda Thank you so much for your answer! I don't want to bother you, but I am still a bloody beginner, and I don't understand why still so many elements are red. What do you need to add that it works? Sorry if I bother you Best regards getNordic:)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of File where things are red

Comment: @SahilManchanda https://imgur.com/a/ZxKNOwL Ty so much

Comment: I've updated my answer, please make sure that R.id.webview matches with id in activity_main layout file

Comment: @SahilManchanda Dear Manchanda, when I try to run the app it won't open and I receive a message that says "eventster has stopped". Do you know why? Best regards

Comment: and in activity_main.xml the .MainActivity is red here are the images: https://i.imgur.com/788uvGG.png and https://i.imgur.com/Sp5wKHG.png

Comment: most likely your webview id is wrong. i will upload a demo app tomorrow

Comment: @SahilManchanda ty so much you are my hero

Comment: here is the temp link to the project https://transfernow.net/92bcq1w4oqaf

Comment: @SahilManchanda it works perfectly! don't know how to thank you! You made my day! Ty so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you need to hide the section:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    WebView webview;
    final String URL = "http://www.eventster.it";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('main-carousel2').style.display='none';", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                        Log.e(TAG,value);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl(URL);
    }
}
```

The thing is you are asking webview to hide a content which isn't loaded yet i.e you need to wait until the webView finish loading the full page so that you can hide the content.